# MySQL set with where condition

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Please tell me how to apply this query.

I want to set `first position` in `remarks`, where student `sgpa` is the highest.

I've tried the following:

```
update mcs1 
set remarks = "First position" 
where sgpa = top 1 
order by sgpa asc
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question clearly:

```
UPDATE mcs1
SET remarks = 'First position'
ORDER BY sgpa DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Set the `remarks` for the highest `sgpa`